# What's the current best solution for generating HTML from ASP.NET Razor templates within a Console Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, servicestack

I want to do this:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

And it appears that http://razorengine.codeplex.com is perfect, except it's a year old.

EDIT: Turns out that RazorEngine has moved to GitHub and had a commit a few months back: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

I noticed that Service Stack has some Razor self-hosting but while there's a long page here http://razor.servicestack.net there's no "hello world you can totally do this from a console."

What's the current best solution for generating HTML from ASP.NET Razor templates within a Console Application?

Comment: Try this too https://github.com/jlamfers/RazorMachine

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> What's the current best solution for generating HTML from ASP.NET
>   Razor templates within a Console Application?

[`RazorEngine`](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine). Full stop.

Comment: Would you recommend any blog that goes step by step to get this work? I have been looking last an hour and this is the only link I found http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-introduction/#start. I followed the tutorial but getting error saying Errors while compiling a Template.

Comment: FYI: "This project is searching for new maintainers, so if you want to help write on gitter or start sending PRs :)"

Answer (score 14):

ServiceStack is another option for rendering Razor view pages. Although it's optimized for integration into a **ASP.NET** or **HttpListener** Web Host (and provides API's for auto-discovering and registering view pages in a directory, re-compiling modified pages on the fly, etc), it also supports static generation of view pages:

```
var razor = new RazorFormat {
    VirtualPathProvider = new InMemoryVirtualPathProvider(new BasicAppHost()),
    EnableLiveReload = false, //don't scan for file system for changes
}.Init();

var page = razor.CreatePage("Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!");
var html = razor.RenderToHtml(page, new { Name = "World" });
html.Print();
```

[Here's the stand-alone unit test of this example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests/Formats_Razor/StandAloneExampleTests.cs).

The benefits of using ServiceStack's Razor view rendering engine includes access to many of the MVC's HtmlHelpers that were ported to ServiceStack. You can also easily host a razor website from a self-hosted ServiceStack HttpListener as seen in [razor-console.servicestack.net](http://razor-console.servicestack.net/), the source code of which is available in a [Self-Hosted Console Application](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.SelfHost) or [Windows Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WinService).

Comment: ServiceStack has gone commercial; if you're not writing open source you will likely have to license it. Older versions are BSD; newer are GNU Affero  GPL (unless licensed). See https://servicestack.net/download and https://servicestack.net/pricing

Answer (score 2):

Nancy has a self-host option and an ability to plug Razor as a view engine.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-wcf

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine

Comment: Do you think that's a little overkill for a console app? I'm not trying to serve up HTML, I'm trying to generate it.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't beat the RazorMachine in terms of simplicity. But if you ever need a lightweight host, you have a candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this the "current best" solution.  However, I found it quite interesting and it will let you accomplish what you are trying to do.  It just isn't very neatly wrapped up.  http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/11/16/hosting-razor-outside-of-aspnet-revised-for-mvc3-rc.html/

Comment: Thanks, looks useful, but it seems like either RazorEngine or @MikeSW's pointer to RazorMachine is best.

Comment: link is broken, actual link withoul last slash: http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/11/16/hosting-razor-outside-of-aspnet-revised-for-mvc3-rc.html Unfortunately, cant edit answer because it requires 6 chars of changes instead on one :)