# How to add foreach iterator to MarkdownPage in ServiceStack Markdown?

Tags: c#, markdown, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack to render my Markdown, however I am doing it programatically for what I am after. Basically my code looks like this :

```
//MarkdownRenderer.cs
var rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
var format = new MarkdownFormat { VirtualPathProvider = new PathProvider() };
var pageTitle = "Test for StackOverflow";
var pageContent = "Foobar";
var page = new MarkdownPage(format, rootPath, pageTitle, pageContent)
{
    Template = "~/_Layout.cshtml"
};
format.AddPage(page);
var view = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"PageTitle", pageTitle},
    {"ArrayData", new[]{"abc","def"}}
};
var html = format.RenderDynamicPageHtml(pageTitle, view);
```

and I have a Markdown page like this:

```
//_Layout.cshtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><!--@PageTitle--></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        @foreach var item in ArrayData {
            - @item
        }
        </div>
        <div><!--@Body--></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The @Body tag fills in perfectly as expected, as does the @PageTitle tag. I now want to be able to get the @foreach code working, and from the documentation available I was unable to work it out. Is the problem my syntax? Do I need to dump the code into a seperate file, and compile that seperately and then inject it's results into my markdown page the same way I am doing the @SwapVariables ?

Any and all help would be highly appreciated, and if you have any questions, please do ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing [ServiceStack's MVC Razor support](http://razor.servicestack.net) with [Markdown Razor format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Markdown-Razor). i.e. Anything that ends with **.cshtml** is a MVC Razor page, whilst only pages ending with **.md** are processed as Markdown Razor pages.

In Markdown Razor the Layout/template page is commonly named `default.shtml` and is only a static HTML page that supports replacement of variable place holders e.g `<!--@Body-->`, only pages with Markdown (i.e. not HTML templates) ending with **.md** get processed as Markdown Razor.

Here's an example of a [Stand-alone Markdown Razor program](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2012/07/servicestacks-markdown-razor-engine-wow/), whilst here's a [stand-alone example using ServiceStack's MVC Razor support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14263254/85785).

Comment: I will give it a go once I finish up at the office. I think you're right though, I am mixing up terminologies... I want standard page content (currently stored as *.md in a database), transformed on the fly and injected into the [at]Body replacement tag (which works), and I want a foreach iterator which will help me extract page components such as NavBar, Twitter feed, etc in a seperate physical *.md file, and the result of which injected into a replacement [at]Tag. I've been trying to do everything in one place.

Comment: Exactly as you suggested, I was a bit confused which made my research for the answer a bit difficult. I had already seen the Stand-alone link and my code was based off of it, the other SS link was very useful though! Not only have I got my code working better now, but I have managed to split it up into an extra couple interfaces which made my NUnit tests easier to write. Thanks again!