# Can Servicestack Razor Pages be compiled at design time

Tags: servicestack, razorgenerator

I am building an app that consists of a number of plugins.  The app and the plugins are built around the service stack framework including the razor engine.

One of the problems I have is that I have to set all of the files to copy always, the final app ends up with a mashup of files from all the plugins.  It works but doesn't make it easy to add/remove plugins - ultimately I would like to do this whilst the app is running.

I found [razorgenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) which looks like it addresses part of my problem and would precompile the microsoft razor pages into the dll.  Has anybody done anything like this with the service stack razor files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't really designed for it, but here's an example of using ServiceStack to [render stand-alone razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14263254/85785).

You could also use another tool like razorgenerator or RazorEngine though this is disconnected and doesn't have anything to do with the Razor support in ServiceStack.